# Как получать и проверять номер состояния, которые мы указываем в команде RAISEERROR в python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Началось с того,что я реализовал все запросы sql через курсор в функциях python и вызывал их соответственно.
Потом мне сказали, что хранимые процедуры и функции и т.п. лучше обрабатывать в ms sql, и вызывать их просто в python, я так и сделал, но если допустим, я делаю несколько RAISEERROR в sql, то я не понимаю как обрабатывать их в python, если ответ не выдаёт никакого состояния в консоли(**например: состояние 1 обрабатывать так,а состояние 2 обрабатывать так**).

**Рандомный пример с raiseerror'ами на sql:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_user]
(
    @str nvarchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @str = N'var1'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('ошибка 1 - %s' , 16, 1, @str) 
    END;
    IF @str = N'var2'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('ошибка 1 - %s' , 16, 2, @str) 
    END;
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.local_username = @str
END
```

**Функция на python:**

```
def get_user(local_user) -> list:
    cursor = Database().cursor
    cursor.execute(f"EXEC get_user N'{local_user}'")
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return res
```

Думал просто проверять текст ошибки, но даже до текста ошибки нельзя добраться(пробовал cursor.fetchone())
**Вызов функций соответственно:**

```
    try:
        print(get_user('var1'))
        print(get_user('var2'))
    except ProgrammingError as PR:
        #тут должна быть обработка разных ошибок
        pass
```

Вывод ошибки без блока try-except:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]ошибка 1 - var1 (50000) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Возможно я не знаю каких то особенностей ошибок в python или sql(мой первый проект на python с sql, который не просто решать задачи на вычисления)

Comment: Ну вот попробуйте напечатать, что у вас в переменной `PR` получается, когда исключение ловите через `except ProgrammingError as PR:`. Кстати, почему такое название переменной - чтоб никто не догадался?

Comment: На счёт переменной PR, ошибься. Хотел написать PE. Вот что выводит:
`('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]ошибка 1 - var1 (50000) (SQLExecDirectW)')`. Пытался получать PE[1], так нельзя)

Comment: Попробуйте взять `PE.args[1]`, ну и вообще посмотрите что в `PE.args`

Comment: `PE.args[1] = [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]ошибка 1 - var1 (50000) (SQLExecDirectW)`

Comment: Ну вот, по крайней мере до текста ошибки вы добрались. Можете там найти строку `var` и взять цифру после неё.

Comment: Мне кажется это костыль, но это лучше чем ничего. А как получать состояние, которое отправляется в RAISEERROR? Может как то по-другому можно его отправить. Я пробовал в sql и throw. Можно было написать типо "SELECT error.msg()", но это как минимум неправильно, когда человеку высвечивается ошибка выборкой

Comment: А `Database` это что вообще, какой библиотекой вы к `SQL` обращаетесь? Нужно в эту библиотеку думаю копать.

Comment: Я использую, как писал в вопросе базу данных ms sql, к нему библиотека pyodbc, Database - мой класс, в котором в __init__ он подключается к базе данных по логину и паролю. Я уже немного чекал документацию pyodbc на гитхабе, хорошо ещё посмотрю

Comment: Да не факт, что что-то получится, но копать надо явно в сторону возможностей библиотеки. Эта часть в питоне не стандартизирована. Что библиотека обработает и вернёт - то и будет.